# What does ASPX Trace First(s) and Lasts(s) mean?

Tags: asp.net, performance, trace

I have been charged with improving the performance of an ASPX website. I'm enabling Tracing so I can look at performance times, but I don't understand what is meant by First(s) and Last(s). What do these mean?

Also, it appears I can add custom events, but I don't know what the times mean on those either.

[image: Trace Information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tracing is enabled, it will monitor each of the requests that are made by your application to allow you to go through and troubleshoot possible issues as well as gauge things like performance. When you are looking at a specific tracing record, the properties that you mentioned would have some type of value (e.g. the From First  would indicate how long after your first trace message that the current trace was processed, and From Last would indicate how many seconds elapsed since the previous trace).

Does that make sense? I'll try to demonstrate what these mean in a very primitive diagram below :

```
First Trace -------------> Another Trace -------------> Current Trace 
            ----------------(From First)-------------->               
                                         -(From Last)->
```

Get More info from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386420(v=vs.100)

Comment: Thank you. I really had to study your answer and the explanation on the page, but I think I get it now.